# Chart.js bar chart with time on X axis and category on Y axis is not rendered

Tags: angular, charts, chart.js

Using the latest chart.js I am unable to create a bar chart with time on X and category on Y axis.

```
<div style="display: block;">
  <canvas baseChart 
    [datasets]="barChartData"
    [options]="barChartOptions"
    [plugins]="barChartPlugins"
    [legend]="barChartLegend"
    [chartType]="barChartType">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

typescript:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ChartOptions, ChartType, ChartDataSets } from 'chart.js';
import { Label } from 'ng2-charts';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  public barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time'
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        type: 'category',
        labels: ['Yes', 'No']
      }]
    }
  };

  public barChartType: ChartType = 'line';
  public barChartLegend = false;

  public barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    { data: [
      {x: new Date('2020-02-20'), y: 'Yes'}, 
      {x: new Date('2020-02-22'), y: 'No'},
      {x: new Date('2020-02-23'), y: 'Yes'},
      {x: new Date('2020-02-24'), y: 'No'}
      ] 
    }
  ];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

This provides nice line chart but once I change the type to 'bar', nothing is rendered.

Line is perfect:
[image: Line is perfect]

Bar is empty:

[image]

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-bar-template-aolnys

Comment: the problem is the data, how do you want to represent the same in bar chart?

Comment: @Sajeetharan - I want to see 4 bars :-) Imagine door status - doors were open on 20th, 22nd, 23rd, 24th but closed on 21st. Or air quality - good, average, poor. I also tried to change data structure from [x, y] to separate labels and data but no luck.

Comment: you cannot have x and two different values for y on bar charts , you could have numbers though

Comment: @Sajeetharan There is always one Y value for one X value in data. If I put numbers on Y axis, it works but I want to see a value in specific category. Like there is an excellent air quality on Sunday, poor on Monday, no measurement on Tuesday... What is wrong on such chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define your `yAxis` values as numbers. In my code "Yes" = 2 and "No" = 1.

```
data: [2, 1, 2, 1]
```

Then use `yAxist.ticks.callback` to return meaningful tick labels

```
yAxes: [{
  ticks: {
    beginAtZero: true,
    stepSize: 1,
    callback: value => {
      if (value == 0) {
        return '';
      }
      return value == 1 ? 'No' : 'Yes';
    }
  }
}]
```

Please have a look at the following [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-bar-template-ydx3ir?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Nice trick! Thank you! I am still curious why category type does not work...